# How to bind an array to JComboBox dynamically?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I binding an array to `JComboBox` like following:

```
String[] arr={"ab","cd","ef"};
final JComboBox lstA = new JComboBox(arr);
```

but I want bind array to `JComboBox` dynamically like following :

```
final JComboBox lstA = new JComboBox();
void bind()
{
    String[] arr={"ab","cd","ef"};
    // bind arr to lstA     
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little odd workaround(mine :)), might useful to you

```
final JComboBox lstA = new JComboBox();
String[] arr={"ab","cd","ef"};
lstA.setModel(new JComboBox(arr).getModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

build your JComboBox with a dynamic [ComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html)

```
JComboBox(ComboBoxModel<E> aModel)
```

like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html

```
m=new DefaultComboBoxModel();
j=JComboBox(m);
```

you can then add and remove elements:

```
m.addElement("ab")
m.addElement("cd")
```

or, if you only need to put the array in the combox:

```
new JComboBox(new Sring[]{"ab","cd","ef"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final JComboBox lstA = new JComboBox();
void bind()
{
  String[] arr={"ab","cd","ef"};
  // bind arr to lstA 
  lstA.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(arr));    
}
```